# Power BI / add refresh button on report view

Tags: .net, powerbi, business-intelligence

I don't have much expertise in Power BI. I started work on it and found it very easy and I've created a report. That report is working fine.

Now, I've requirements to add Refresh button on the report that will refresh the data source and get the latest data from it. I tried to search alots on it but still, I'm not able to find any reasonable solution.

Do we have that kind of functionality available on Power BI?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are working on powerbi.com, the end user cannot refresh the data in a report manually (though it is possible to manually refresh a dataset in a workspace if you have permissions to the workspace and have a data gateway set up).

You can either set up a refresh schedule or else build your report using a [DirectQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-use-directquery) which will always use the current data.

Answer (score 2):

You can embed a PowerApp that calls a FLOW that calls the Power BI API to trigger a manual refresh.   I found this posting very helpful in setting it up:
[Article by Konstantinos Ioannou](https://medium.com/@Konstantinos_Ioannou/refresh-powerbi-dataset-with-microsoft-flow-73836c727c33)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: To put it simply - I did my research and yes - this is possible like so:

1) Create a PowerApp with a single button "Refresh" 
2) Create a Microsoft flow to refresh a dataset with a post request - hard coding the dataset for your report
3) Given the PowerApp button an action to launch the Flow
4) Add the PowerApp with the button to your report using the PowerApps custom visual. 
5) Press the button. 

Pros - this does work to initiate the dataset refresh. That said, the visuals do not update until you refresh the report page and you also have to be logged in with a powerapps license.

Answer (score 0):

I chose a direct query for retrieving the updated data into the PowerBI report.You can set the refresh rate in dataset settings.I did set it to 15 mins. After 15 mins it was refreshing in Power bi workspace online.But the embedded report deployed on the website was refreshing within an hour.I think there is no way to manually refresh the embedded report instantly.It automatically refreshes within an hour. As for the report in Power bi workspace, it can be manually refreshed instantly by checking
  dataset settings-> refresh now.