# How to choose a random field from data set with the press of an image/button

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm playing around with Power BI trying to learn some new stuff. I created a DAX measure using RAND() and set that as the value for a table with TOP N of 1.

[image]
[image]

So what I'm trying to do is on the press of an image (I can use a button if an image cannot do this) is to use the random measure to pick 1 value from the City column, which contains 30,000 cities. The results will display in that table below.

So far its correctly choosing a different city when I reload the page, but I'm not sure how to bind this to a button/image, or if I even can. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. It sounds like measures are only evaluated when you first define them or when you refresh your dataset (see https://www.jetglobal.com/blog/calculated-columns-vs-measures/), and there doesn't appear to be any way to refresh the data manually from the report view (see [Power BI / add refresh button on report view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184992/power-bi-add-refresh-button-on-report-view)).

EDIT: Thinking more about this. If you were really determined to have this kind of functionality, a pseudo-random workaround might be to assign a RAND() value to each city as a calculated column, then select the top 10 or so and set up your bookmarks so that clicking on the button would iterate through those top 10, creating the effect of randomness. The downside would be if they clicked through all 10 the loop would repeat, but if the report was on a frequent refresh schedule, the top 10 would be different (and truly random) as long as they didn't click more than 10 times (or however high you're willing to go) between refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, quite easily, with R visual. R visuals are dynamic. They will change whenever the input data changes. The input data may depend i.e. on the slicer selection which may be used to trigger generating random number.

Create a table with city list. Read it to R dataframe. And choose from the dataframe one randomly picked row. Then display data with a plot. I can suggest for example this package:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/stargazer-package-for-beautiful-latex-tables-from-r-statistical-models-output/